# VLC not recording video streaming, just audio?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, mpeg-dash

I am using VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari to stream an m4s contents as I want to compare the streamed video with my original one. When I am watching it, I click on the record button. Then I click it again to stop recording and browse to where the mp4 file is created. When I click on it, it just contains the audio, not the video (the screen is blank). Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks,

Comment: Is the stream maybe encrypted - if you could share an example that might help?